# How to manipulate windows programs

Tags: .net, windows

I have a windows application that I need to be able to manipulate programatically. The program was written to use version 2 of the .NET framework. Is there any library or method to programatically manipulate the elements of this program (it most likely does not use standard windows forms components). Ideally, I need to be able to simulate mouse clicks and grab strings of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [my post in a thread about sending messages to windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083954/send-message-in-c/5084190#5084190).

With the use of such API functions, you can easily control or alter other windows.  Common examples would be maximizing another window, minimizing another window, hiding another window from view, grabbing another window and placing it within your own window (setting its parent,) altering another window's title, altering the text within another window's textboxes (etc.,) sending keystrokes & mouse clicks to a window (or one of its buttons,) running menus within another window, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[ManagedSpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx) will let you do this.  Since this is a .NET application, you could also (maybe) use Reflection to dynamically instantiate objects from classes in the application, but this wouldn't necessarily be exactly what you're looking to do.