# Simulating multitouch with Kinect Skeleton joints ( SDK1.5 )

Tags: c#, wpf, image-manipulation, kinect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Simulating multitouch with Kinect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454572/c-sharp-simulating-multitouch-with-kinect)

I am trying to write an Image Manipulation application using WPF and Kinect SDK 1.5.

Reading some articles on the web, I saw that is possible to manipulate an image using methods provided by WPF Touch, but I don't know how to associate my skeleton's hand-joints with the multitouch points?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [C# Simulating multitouch with Kinect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454572/c-sharp-simulating-multitouch-with-kinect) as it is a duplicate, and see [anathonlines's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454572/c-sharp-simulating-multitouch-with-kinect/11473131#11473131):

"What you want is to [send messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083954/send-message-in-c-sharp) to the window in question. The message you need to compose is the [`WM_TOUCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317341%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. You can find a very helpful discussion thread on `WM_TOUCH` [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tabletandtouch/thread/e5c87731-86e4-4c25-9278-86cb0dd4ff8a/)."