# Creating a WM_TOUCH message for PostMessage() in C# / .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, multi-touch, wm-touch

(For background, see [Composing a WM_TOUCH message for SendMessage(), Kinect as a multi-touch device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081167/composing-a-wm-touch-message-for-sendmessage-kinect-as-a-multi-touch-device) which asks basically the same question as mine but whose accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question. The tricky bit isn't filling in `TOUCHINPUT` structures but making a valid touch input handle.)

I would like to simulate the presence of a multi-touch input device in a nasty hackish way, which in outline goes like this:

```
while (true) {
  choose locations etc. for simulated touches;
  PostMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_TOUCH, nTouches, ...);
}
```

The tricky bit is what goes in that space labelled "...". The MSDN documentation, which is unsurprisingly written from the point of view of a *consumer* of `WM_TOUCH` messages, says that the `lParam` for the `WM_TOUCH` message is

> a touch input handle that can be used in a call to `GetTouchInputInfo` to retrieve detailed information about the touch points associated with this message.

I can easily enough make, e.g., an array of `TOUCHINPUT` structures, which is what `GetTouchInputInfo` gives you. But that seems to be an entirely different thing from a "touch input handle". (E.g., a touch input handle needs to be the right sort of thing to pass to `CloseTouchInputHandle`, which allegedly `PostMessage` or `SendMessage` will do.)

**Is it possible (officially or unofficially!) for user code to generate a valid touch input handle that it can pass to `PostMessage`?** If so, how?

Comment: Saying "no way" is hard to do.  Hmm, no, no way.  You'd need the equivalent of SendInput(), it doesn't exist for touch.

Comment: That was my guess too! I was just hoping that there might be some evil undocumented hacky way to do it. (E.g., maybe a touch input handle is really, under the hood, just a pointer to a bunch of TOUCHINPUT structures -- though that would require some highly improbable magic since pointers can't meaningfully be passed between processes.) Does your "no way" mean "no legal way" or "definitely no way, including nasty hacks"?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 has a TouchInjection API for faking touches in the Desktop Environment.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6460.simulating-touch-input-in-windows-8-using-touch-injection-api.aspx