# How to call a paint event from the mouse click event?

Tags: c#

I am having a mouse click event and i want to call a paint event of a picture box from this mouse click event, the paint event uses the event argument of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the Invalidate method of the picture.

Comment: thats nice but in general if it dint support the invalidate then how should i communicate in this sort of cases, the same situation may come across with some other kind events then is there any Generalise way to work around this?

Comment: The Invalidate method is something supported in any Winforms control. It's the managed way to feed a WM_PAINT native message. What do you mean as "support"?

Comment: I mean i were to deal with some other kind of 2 events where i had to call one form another then is there a general way to work around this?

Comment: If I'm understanding well, your two forms should interact each other? If so, I'd create a proxy, where both the forms should subscribe, then listen to the messages. Could you show a minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

In case there is the method `Invalidate` which is specifically desing to do what you need to, and you **don't** want to follow that obvious way, the alternative is to

[`Send Message`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083954/send-message-in-c-sharp) `WM_PAINT` to that control.