# If another instance is running, [set focus] and open file on the 'old' instance

Tags: c#, wpf, setfocus, single-instance

How can i check if another instance is running ? 
Also if it is running how can I force my already opened instance to open a file ? 
Also if it is possible can I force it to get focus? ( I need this seperate)

Comment: Please specify your question. What `instance` exactly do you want to check?

Comment: @CliveDM program instance. I mean if already my program is running then open file to the already opened instance (not the new).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i check if another instance is running ?

You could use `Process.GetProcesses()` to get a list of processes which are running on your machine. And simply do your compare with `Process.Name`. With rather simple name, you may need additional check for your application.

> Also if it is running how can I force my already opened instance to
>   open a file ?

If you want to communicate between 2 processes, I would recommend `SendMessage` method. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083954/send-message-in-c-sharp).

> Also if it is possible can I force it to get focus? ( I need this
>   seperate)

You could use `SetForgoundWindow` method (also require `P/Invoke`). See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Better hope nobody else has the same process name.  I've seen two totally unrelated programs with a conflict like this, although it's nastier--the offending program sends a close to the other program.

Comment: About using `Process.GetProcesses()` @LorenPechtel has right. 
Now about communicating between 2 processes , the article that u linked me it says that I should better avoid using SendMessage method.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Yes, it'll require some more check if the process's name is rather simple.

Comment: @Mitcoc I don't see any `avoid` there. As for the answer in that link, it recommends to use `event` to send and receive events, **in one program**. And your question is about communicate between 2 **different** programs (although it's the same `.exe` file you ran, but it do runs in different context), with absolutely no relate to each other. So the `event` could not be use under this circumstance.

Comment: @CliveDM I found a way to detect if another instance is running via `mutex`. About SendMessage you had right. Im going to use it. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @Mitcoc Glad to help. As for `mutex` do you mean the class `System.Threading.Mutex`?

Comment: @CliveDM [yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application?rq=1)